# PHP - Access data for .env laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am starting the program with Laravel and I have in my **".env"** file my access data to the server:

```
USER_SERVER=user
PASSWORD_SERVER=123456789
```

I have my role in my controller:

```
 public function connectServer()
    {
        $connection=ssh2_connect(172.17.2.33, 22);
        ssh2_auth_password($connection, USER_SERVER, PASSWORD_SERVER);

$stream=ssh2_exec($connection, "df -h");
        $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
}
```

My role above has problems. What is the correct way to call the user and password of my **".env"** file for my function?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the configuration system for these values. You can add to a current configuration file in the `config` folder or create your own that returns an associative array. We will use the `env()` helper to pull the values you set in the `.env` file:

```
<?php

return [
   ...
   'server' => [
       'user' => env('USER_SERVER', 'some default value if you would like'),
       'password' => env('PASSWORD_SERVER', ...),
    ],
    ...
];
```

If you added this key to the `services.php` file in the `config` folder you would then access this configuration value via the `Config` facade or the `config()` helper function:

```
// if we want a value from the services.php file
Config::get('services.server.user');
config('services.server.user');

// if you want all of them for that server array
$config = config('services.server');
echo $config['user'];
```

Using the configuration system this way allows you to use the "config caching" that Laravel provides, as you will not have any `env()` calls in your application, except for in the config files, which can be cached. [When configuration caching is in place it doesn't load the env]

> "If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null`." - [Laravel 7.x Docs - Configuration - Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching)

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Configuration - Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) `config()`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Configuraiton - Retrieving Environmental Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration) `env()`